# Inbox system php, I want to display the latest sender first

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create an inbox system in PHP, I want to display the most recent sender first, for example when a contact send me a message I want him to be the first name on the list but unfortunately that's not the result I get, my contact's name doesn't appear on the top of the list even though the latest message is from him. Thanks

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE id_recipient = ? GROUP BY id_sender ORDER BY id DESC");
$query->execute([$id_recipient]);

while ($messages = $query->fetch()) {
  //view
}
```

Comment: Change your ORDER BY so it sorts unread messages first. We can't see your data structure so we can't say anything more specific than that, but I'm going to guess you have a column which records whether a message has been opened or not. Maybe you also have a column for the date the message was sent? You could order by that instead / as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  sorting unread messages it's a good idea, I'll give it a try